# Request Aborted on posting params using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, httprequest

By using a `ANCHOR` tag , I am trying to redirect to `http://google.com` via `HREF` but at the same time I am posting some parameters to my another page via `AJAX`.Redirection is working fine but the parameters posting request is getting aborted.
Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){    
   $('#c').click(function(){           
     $.post("mypage.php?param1=abc1212",function(data){
     });
   });
 return false;  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="c" href="http://google.com" class='test'> Click 2 Call</a>
```

Now page perfectly move to google but the POST request which is `mypage.php?param1=abc1212` is getting aborted.I dont know why?
I can see `status = aborted` in firebug
I have searched alot but didn't get clue
Please Guide me about that why this problem is occurring and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```
 $(function(){    
   $('#c').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();           
     $.post("mypage.php?param1=abc1212",function(data){
         window.location.href = "http://google.com";
     });
   });
 return false;  
});
```

preventDefault stops the anchor from redirecting when clicked so that you can do your ajax.
Once your ajax is done then redirect to google.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){    
   $('#c').click(function(){           
     $.post("mypage.php?param1=abc1212",function(data){
     });
   });

    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
 return false;  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="c" href="#" class='test'> Click 2 Call</a>
```

Comment: As tim's answer is more explainatory so thats why I accepted his answer but as a reward I am voting you up :)